# Flutter RequestNode

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

The last days I tried to implement fixes I found here on stackoverflow, but they all do not work. I think this is caused of the unnormal storyline:

- I have a screen with Textfields
- By click on the FloatingActionButton a popup appears, where the user can click on buttons
- With click on a button I set a bool to true (for example: textfield1 = true)
- This triggers a TextField on my screen ( if (textfield1== true) {TextField()}
  This all works fine, the problem is, that I want to change the focus on this new TextField:

So I added this:

```
textfield1=true; _focusTextField1();
```

with

```
void _focusTextField1() { FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(textfield1Node);}
```

Now the TextField has the focus (the border gets blue), but the textmarker doesn't appear (I hope textmarker is the right word, I mean this " | " which also triggers the keyboard.)
I have to click on the button (FloatingActionButton--> Popup-->Button) twice, to trigger this textmarker / keyboard. 
Than I found this solution:

```
   void initState() {
super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _focusTextField1());
```

This also doesn't work. The next problem would be, that I have to implement this `addPostFrameCallback` for every possible new TextField the user can create, but in the description of the `addPostFrameCallback` it says that only the last callback will be triggerd, means: Everytime I create a new TextField the TextField which has the last Callback in may initState() will be focused.

Thanks for your help!
(I provided all relevant code, I think if I provide all the code this would be confusing)

Comment: Am I understand correctly, you want to call `_focusTextField1()` inside `initState()` but doesn't work

Comment: @MohamedSayed No. I call `_fcousTextField1()` when the user clicks on the button which also sets `textField1=true` /creates the new TextField. Because this approach to focus the new TextField doesn't work, I found the approach to call `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _focusTextField1());` in the initState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is FocusNode:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

U can create:

```dart
  FocusNode myFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }
```

and add this to your TextField:

```dart
  TextField(
    focusNode: myFocusNode,
  ),
```

So, when u need to request focus, call: `myFocusNode.requestFocus()`

Comment: I did this: `void _focusTextField1() { FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(textfield1Node);}`
(Of course I added `textfield1Node = FocusNode();`and `focusNode: textfield1Node`in my code)

Comment: Sorry! You are right `myfocusNode.requestFocus()` solves the problem. I thought `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(textfield1Node);` would do the same...thanks!